# Sending ATA commands to SATA Drive on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, driver

Any one please help on sending ATA commands to SATA Drive on Mac OS.

As per the Apple docs, its not possible to send it from Application and is recommended to write a Logical Unit Driver. There is not much document on the same for ATA family.

Provider class for SATA device is IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice.

Please shed some light on writing the Logical Unit driver for sending the ATA commands and  on the classes need to be sub classed since the IOAHCIFamily is not open source and is private on Mac.

Thanks for any advice.......

Comment: Search for FreeBSD device drivers as that is the basis for Mac OS X

Answer (score 0):

will it help since Logical Unit Driver is based on IOKit on mac.
I am new to driver programming...